# Debian in Parallels VM installed with no GUI

Tags: linux, macos, debian, virtual-machine

I installed Debian with Parallels VM in the macBook Pro. I selected the Graphical installation but not it starts as the command line. I entered as `root` and run the command `tasksel` that opens this dialogue box,

[image]

and, here I would like to installed the `Debian desktop environment`. In the interface, how many times I press `Enter`, nothing happens.

As I mentioned, I have a MacBook keyboard and seems the cmd is active then the software selection dialogue box. What to do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have an ASCII-based GUI there. Just going to an item and hitting <kbd>Enter/Return</kbd> won’t work. You have to actually check off that item and then navigate to the `<Ok>` and click that.

To do that you are going to use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Space</kbd> key and then <kbd>Enter/Return</kbd>.

Use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to move up and down the list. Hit <kbd>Space</kbd> to select an item and then—when you are done—hit the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key until you head down to to that `<Ok>`, hit <kbd>Enter/Return</kbd> and you should be good to go.